# What are the main differences between Ballerina version 0.991.0 and 1.0.0?

Tags: version, upgrade, ballerina

I started a project using Ballerina 0.991.0 last week.Now Ballerina 1.0.0 alpha version has been released.

What are the major differences between two versions if I upgrade my Ballerina version to 1.0.0.

Comment: Please follow the ballerina-1.0.0-alpha [release note](https://ballerina.io/downloads/release-notes/) for the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.0.0-alpha release is based on the [language specification 2019R2](https://v1-0-0-alpha.ballerina.io/learn/language-specification/2019R2/) which will be used for 1.0.0 GA release. Also future releases will based on that specification with the backward compatibility.

The significant advantage with related to 0.991.0 release is Java interoperability and performance improvements.

Therefore in long term it would be better migrating to alpha.
Please refer [1.0.0-alpha release notes](https://ballerina.io/downloads/release-notes/#100alphanotes).

Answer (score 1):

Let me elaborate a little bit more. Here are some key highlights of Ballerina 1.0.0

- Based on a stable language specification: 2019R3. We are not planning to introduce major incompatible language changes after this release. Please refer the release note to more information about various language changes from 0.991 to 1.0.0-alpha.
- Introduces a brand new Ballerina compiler back-end that targets the JVM. This new compiler produces an executable .jar file for your Ballerina program. We've removed the compiler that produces .balx files.
- Significant performance improvements over the previous Ballerina runtime (BVM)
- Java interoperability (allows you to call Java code from Ballerina)
- Major redesign of Ballerina developer tools